# wxPython | delete items from dataViewListCtrl several times

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I think I got a big problem with deleting items from dataViewListCtrl in wxPython.
I have a dataViewListCtrl with several rows. The user can mark and delete the rows.
To get the selection I use the method GetSelections() from the dataViewListCtrl like:

```
def delSektion(self, event):
    tmpo = self.frame.m_dvlc.GetSelections()
    for i in tmpo:
        print "test"
```

So I get a list of DataViewItems. To identify this items I use the method getID() from the DataViewItem.
With this id I can delete the rows in the DataViewListCtrl with the method DeleteItem().

**And now the problem:**

If the user did this several times the index of the rows in DataViewListCtrl changed. But the ItemID is still the same so I have no connections between the ItemID of the DataViewItem and the RowID of the DataViewListCtrl.

I hope you understand what I mean and my horrible English - sorry!

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you create a small, runnable example? I would think the Item ID would be unique enough. You shouldn't rely on the Row number though.

Comment: Thanks, but find a solution. There is a method called ItemToRow() like this: 
        for sektion in self.frame.m_dvlc.GetSelections():
            item_id = self.frame.m_dvlc.ItemToRow(sektion)
            self.frame.m_dvlc.DeleteItem(item_id)